# Find the maximal $n$ satisfying $a_n \geq \frac{1}{10}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> 3. Let $a_n$ be the $n$-th term of the following sequence $$\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{3}{9},\frac{5}{9},\frac{1}{16},\frac{3}{16},\frac{5}{16},\frac{7}{16},\frac{1}{25},...$$

From what could I start resolving this problem ? I have found the sequence pattern that the numerator always the odd number which always start again from number 1 if the denominator change pattern. the pattern of the denominator is the square of 1, 2, 3 and etc

I have also found the pattern for the series that

- $a_1 = 1$
- $a_3= 2$
- $a_6 = 3$
- $a_{10} = 4$
- $a_{15}= 5$
- $a_{21} = 6$

  And etc.

But I stucked on this formula, I have no idea to find the maximum n, can anyone give me some suggestion and steps for solving this problem ?

[image]

Comment: This is not clear at all.  You appear to have defined a sequence $\{a_n\}$ for some $n$  though not all.  There's no apparent reason why the definition shouldn't go on forever.  None of this appears to have anything to do with $n≤\frac 1{10}$.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: @lulu I have taken a picture to give it more clear but I do not know how to attach this picture, can u help me ? I am a newbie, thanks before

Comment: I don't know how to attach pictures, sorry. Never done that.

Comment: If you're using a browser, there's an icon at the top left of the _edit_ field that looks like two mountains, one bigger than the other - the standard icon for _picture_, these days, infact - click on that & follow instructions. As for your series, it seems that values both arbitrarily small _and_ arbitrarily close to 1/2 (but<1/2) occur infinitely in it.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey ok thanks I have given my picture now, thank u so much

Comment: @lulu, I have fixed my question, can you help me? the question is asked for n >= by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms of your sequence which are immediately followed by a smaller term are
$$\frac11,\ \frac34,\ \frac59,\ \frac7{16},\ \frac9{25}\ \dots$$
The $k^\text{th}$ one of these is given by the formula $\frac{2k-1}{k^2}$. The last term in your sequence which exceeds or equals $\frac1{10}$ will correspond to the greatest value of $k$ satisfying the inequality $\frac{2k-1}{k^2}\ge\frac1{10}$ or equivalently
$$f(k)=k^2-20k+10\le0$$
Solving the quadratic equation, the zeros of $f(k)$ are $10\pm\sqrt{90}$, so $f(k)\le0$ for $10-\sqrt{90}\le k\le10+\sqrt{90}$. Since the greatest integer below $10+\sqrt{90}$ is $19$, the last term of your sequence above $\frac1{10}$ is
$$\frac{2\cdot19-1}{19^2}=\frac{37}{361}$$
and the position of this term in your sequence is $1+2+3+\cdots+19=190$,
so the short answer to your question is
$$\boxed{a_{190}=\frac{37}{361}}$$

Comment: The short answer is $n=190$ ;-)

Comment: Thankyou @bof, you explained it very clear ! But I wonder about the sequence, can we neglect the 1/4, 1/9, 3/9 , ? Actually I have found that on the same denominator if I sum all of it the value is one

Comment: @AsterZen Since you're looking for the **last** term in the sequence which is greater than or equal to 1/10, we can disregard the 1/4, 1/9, 3/9 because each of them is immediately followed by a bigger term.  So we just look at the last and biggest term with each denominator.

Answer (score 0):

The general terms are

$$\frac{2k+1}{m^2}$$ for $k\in[0,m-1]$, and the largest of a subsequence is

$$\frac{2m-1}{m^2}=\frac2m-\frac1{m^2}.$$

By inspection, $m=20$ is just too large ($\dfrac1{10}-\dfrac1{400}$) so that $19$ is fine. The corresponding $n$ is the $19^{th}$ triangular number, $\color{green}{190}$.

---

Just for fun, the general expression can be written

$$\frac{2n-\left\lceil\dfrac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}2\right\rceil\left(\left\lceil\dfrac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}2\right\rceil-1\right)-1}{\left\lceil\dfrac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}2\right\rceil^2}.$$